# Output logits with softmax aren't extreme when using Tensorflow. No prediction is very confident

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I trained a text classification model on data in TensorFlow and plotted the SoftMax confidence for the correct prediction as well as the SoftMax confidence for incorrect predictions. When I did this I noticed that there were no output predictions with a high logit/class probability. For example, predicting between 4 classes had these results:

(TensorFlow version)

input text: "Text that fits into class 0"

logits: [.3928,  0.2365, 0.1854, 0.1854]

label: class 0

I would hope that the logit output for class 0 would be higher than .3928! Looking at the graph you can see that none of the prediction logits output a number higher than (.5).

[image: Logit Outputs for correct and incorrect predictions]

Next, I retrained the exact same model and dataset but in Pytorch. With Pytorch, I got the results I was looking for. Both models had the exact same validation accuracy after training. (90% val accuracy)

(Pytorch Version)

input text: "Text that fits into class 0"

logits: [0.8778, 0.0532, 0.0056, 0.0635]

label: class 0

Here is what I understand about the softmax function:
The softmax function transforms its inputs, which can be seen as logits, into a probability distribution over the classes. The maximum value of the softmax is 1, so if your largest logit is 0.5, then it means that the highest probability assigned by the softmax will be relatively low (less than 1/2).

To have more extreme outputs, you need to have larger logits. One way to do this is to train your model with more data and a more powerful architecture, so that it can learn more complex relationships between inputs and outputs. It may not be desirable for a model to have extremely high confidence in its predictions, as it could lead to overfitting to the training data. The appropriate level of confidence will depend on the specific use case and the desired trade-off between precision and recall.

My Tensorflow Model:

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('prajjwal1/bert-tiny', from_pt = True)
encoder = TFAutoModel.from_pretrained('prajjwal1/bert-tiny', from_pt = True)

# Define input layer with token and attention mask
input_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_ids")
attention_mask = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name="attention_mask")

# Call the ALBERT model with the inputs
pooler_output = encoder(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)[1] # 1 is pooler output

# Define a dense layer on top of the pooled output
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=params['fc_layer_size'])(pooler_output)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(params['dropout'])(x)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')(x)

# Define a model with the inputs and dense layer
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_ids, attention_mask], outputs=outputs)

loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.0008)
metrics = [tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()]

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss=loss, metrics=metrics)
```

My Pytorch Model:

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('prajjwal1/bert-tiny')
encoder = AutoModel.from_pretrained('prajjwal1/bert-tiny')

loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.0008)

class EscalationClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, encoder):
        super(EscalationClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(128, 312)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(312, 4)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.2)

    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask):
        pooled_output = self.encoder(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)[1]# [0] is last hidden state, 1 for pooler output
        # pdb.set_trace()
        x = self.fc1(pooled_output)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

model = EscalationClassifier(encoder)
```

Can anyone help me explain why my Tensorflow logit outputs aren't more confident like the pytorch outputs? *The problem doesn't seem to be with the softmax itself.

Comment: The problem does not seem to be from the softmax. To explore the accuracy of softmax, you could feed the same vector to softmax of both packages to make sure you get the same correct answer. Regardless, it seems more like you don't compare apple and apple. How do you know the models you train using those packages are the same at the end?

Comment: Good point, I could try looking into that. I used the same stop condition for both (Stop when val_loss doesn't improve for 10 epochs). They both reached the same validation accuracy of around .9) I was hoping someone with good Tensorflow intuition would immedietly recognize a potential fix. I'll think try using a different dataset in the meantime.